# What will happen exactly if I check "Send Contract Expiration Notice Emails to Account and Contract Owners" in Contract Settings?

Tags: workflow, standard-objects, email-alert, contracts

Salesforce Contract settings has this option:

> Send Contract Expiration Notice Emails to Account and Contract Owners

However, this is [the only information I can find](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_contract.htm&type=5) on the Salesforce help site to explain what this does:

> 1. Select Send Contract Expiration Notice Emails to Account and Contract Owners, and then save your changes.
> 2. To stop sending expiration notices, deselect this option, and then save your changes.

My client want to send email notifications to the contract parties at timed intervals, and from what I am reading, this might do that, or might not.

Does anyone know:

1. To which recipients will Salesforce send email notifications to of an expiring contract?
2. Where does it find the email addresses to send the notifications so?
3. How many email notifications (initial and follow-up reminders if any) get sent?
4. What frequency do the follow-up reminders get sent?
5. Is there a specific email template used for the reminders, and is it customizable?

It seems strange to me that this feature is available, yet the Salesforce help site doesn't answer these basic questions about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To which recipients will Salesforce send email notifications to of an
>   expiring contract?

The account owner and contact owner. The fields on Contract, Contact and Account, will determine who this is.

> Where does it find the email addresses to send the notifications so?

The owners' user email.

> How many email notifications (initial and follow-up reminders if any)
>   get sent?

You'll need to check the documentation or test this, but I think it's just **one** reminder *seven days* before the end. I would need to test this or find a specific documentation that spells it out before I can say definitively.

> What frequency do the follow-up reminders get sent?

There is no frequency. It's just once.

> Is there a specific email template used for the reminders, and is it
>   customizable?

No.

---

It's useful for Professional Edition, because they get a little automation, but I think you're looking for a Process or Workflow solution. This would allow you to customize the timing, templates, who's notified, etc.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. If the reminder is seven days out, what does the `Owner Expiration Notice` field used for?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else wondering when/how the notification gets sent, here's documentation from 2021 that provides some more information.

> A daily (run every 24 hours around mid-night) background process
> generates an e-mail notification message for any Contracts expiring
> within the selected "Owner Expiration Notice" field value. This
> assumes a valid contract start date and duration settings have been
> specified to properly calculate a Contract End Date (which the
> expiration notice is based on.)

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325218&type=1

Since it's based on the Owner Expiration Notice field value, you wouldn't be able to send notifications on Timed Intervals. However, if you want to send a one-time notification based on the Owner Expiration Notice field's value, this feature will suit you.

Additionally, the notification is only sent for activated contracts. From the same article:

> In addition, Contract Expiration notification message are delivered for activated contracts only.

Additionally, the automation does not send emails to contacts/customers. It is an internal notification only that is sent to the users who own the account or the contract records:

> Send email notifications to account and contract owners when a
> contract expires.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_contract.htm&type=5